# DuplicateNameException When Getting Diff of Two Tables

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am trying to limit what I post to a web API using more than just the SQL queries by date limits, but to not post things I have already posted previously when nothing has changed.

I have some `DataTables` that are built using Linq like so:

```
var Results = (from item in items.AsEnumerable()
select new
{
    reference_id = pat["Id"],
    last_name = pat["LastName"],
    first_name = pat["FirstName"]
}).Distinct().Reverse().Take(50).Reverse().ToDataTable();

var Results2 = (from item in items.AsEnumerable()
select new
{
    reference_id = pat["Id"],
    last_name = pat["LastName"],
    first_name = pat["FirstName"]
}).Distinct().Reverse().Take(55).Reverse().ToDataTable();
```

That part is working just fine, but then I am trying to have it compare those two `DataTables` to find any rows where any of the values in any column is different or if there are new rows. So in this case it should return 5 rows.

Here is a function that was supposed to give me the diff:

```
public static DataTable getDiffRecords(DataTable FirstDataTable, DataTable SecondDataTable)
{
    if (SecondDataTable.Columns.Count == 0) {
        return FirstDataTable;
    }
    //Create Empty Table 
    DataTable ResultDataTable = new DataTable("ResultDataTable");

    //use a Dataset to make use of a DataRelation object 
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    //Add tables 
    while (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
        DataTable table = ds.Tables[0];
        if (ds.Tables.CanRemove(table))
        {
            ds.Tables.Remove(table);
        }
    }
    ds.Tables.AddRange(new DataTable[] { FirstDataTable.Copy(), SecondDataTable.Copy() });

    //Get Columns for DataRelation 
    DataColumn[] firstColumns = new DataColumn[ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < firstColumns.Length; i++)
    {
        firstColumns[i] = ds.Tables[0].Columns[i];
    }

    DataColumn[] secondColumns = new DataColumn[ds.Tables[1].Columns.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < secondColumns.Length; i++)
    {
        secondColumns[i] = ds.Tables[1].Columns[i];
    }

    //Create DataRelation 
    DataRelation r1 = new DataRelation(string.Empty, firstColumns, secondColumns, false);
    ds.Relations.Add(r1);

    DataRelation r2 = new DataRelation(string.Empty, secondColumns, firstColumns, false);
    ds.Relations.Add(r2);

    //Create columns for return table 
    for (int i = 0; i < FirstDataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        ResultDataTable.Columns.Add(FirstDataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName, FirstDataTable.Columns[i].DataType);
    }

    //If FirstDataTable Row not in SecondDataTable, Add to ResultDataTable. 
    ResultDataTable.BeginLoadData();
    foreach (DataRow parentrow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        DataRow[] childrows = parentrow.GetChildRows(r1);
        if (childrows == null || childrows.Length == 0)
            ResultDataTable.LoadDataRow(parentrow.ItemArray, true);
    }

    //If SecondDataTable Row not in FirstDataTable, Add to ResultDataTable. 
    foreach (DataRow parentrow in ds.Tables[1].Rows)
    {
        DataRow[] childrows = parentrow.GetChildRows(r2);
        if (childrows == null || childrows.Length == 0)
            ResultDataTable.LoadDataRow(parentrow.ItemArray, true);
    }

    ResultDataTable.EndLoadData();

    return ResultDataTable;
}
```

This fails at `ds.Tables.AddRange(new DataTable[] { FirstDataTable.Copy(), SecondDataTable.Copy() });` with the exception `System.Data.DuplicateNameException`.

I run through it twice, but the first time through it should return at the top since the second table is empty. Here is how I execute that:

```
DataTable Temp = rawData;
rawData = getDiffRecords(rawData, PersistentTable);
PersistentTable= Temp;
```

I have tried to clear the DataSet, remove tables and haven't seen any benefit.

Comment: Your `FirstDataTable` and `SecondDataTable` have same names `TableName`. Must have different

Comment: You are right, adding `SecondDataTable.TableName = "SecondDataTable"` to the line before fixed it.